# Trust establishment of iot device in private blockchain

Tags: blockchain

Assume that there are two participants involved in a private blockchain network, a seller and a delivery partner.

Seller wants to track the temperature of the product till it reaches the customer. An iot device is enabled in the product which is expected to send the storage temperature of the product periodically to the blockchain network.

Now my questions are -

1. If the iot device sends the data to seller, and the seller commits the data to ledger, why should the delivery partner trust that data ?
2. If not the above case, if we make the iot device as a participant of the network, than who will be responsible for setting up the device as a participant ? Again, if it is seller or delivery partner, why should one trust the other ?

I am sure I am missing something here, please help me to understand.

Comment: i'm confused, it sounds like you are starting with blockchain and working backwards to make it work. Why are you using blockchain?

Comment: The intention is to make sure the product reaches the customers hand in right conditions, if not, the delivery partner should not be able to deny the fact that the product was not maintained by him under prescribed conditions.

Comment: Why do you think blockchain will solve this problem? What if someone tampers with the iot device?

Comment: I agree that making the device tamper proof is additional area of concern, the problem i expect from blockchain to solve is, if the product delivered to the customer is not in a usable condition, than it should be evident that is it a problem with the product itself or is not maintained under adviced conditions after dispatch.

Comment: You're repeating yourself now. Blockchain does not solve this problem. You can't put a physical device in a "blockchain". You cannot calculate the hash of a physical device.

Answer (score 1):

The data should be uploaded to the blockchain automatically by iot devices. Not by any person or third party.

And there is a way to hash the hardware machine and send to hash value with data, so if someone wants to hack the machine or something like that, the hash value would change and the data associated with it becomes invalid.

Comment: what if someone tampers with the iot device?

Comment: The hash of the IoT device will change

Comment: It’s an anti-tampering technique on hardware aspect

Comment: "The hash of the IoT device"? How exactly do you calculate the hash of a physical object?

Comment: Check this out: https://www.intrinsic-id.com/sram-puf/iot-security-it-starts-with-a-strong-root-of-trust/

Comment: I'd like to know how this works, because I'm skeptical "Using our IP it is possible to reconstruct exactly the same cryptographic key every time and under all environmental circumstances."